# SSRS Email not sending but job successfully completed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS Report Service configuration Manager,

I have done Report Service Windows Share its working fine,but the email(gmail) is not sending but the SQL job agent running and completes the job successfully.i am using **windows 8 professional system**,In many sites SMTP Server manager, is configured but i not have that one i don't know how to handle this issue kindly give me some suggestion to overcome this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look into "testing SMTP with Telnet". This will show you if the email can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx) link, it is a step by step guide of debugging smpt via telnet. It should who why your gmail accounts to not receive a report.